# Django: How to exclude model fields in all the admin pages?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My project has multiple models and custom admin pages for the models. All the models inherit from a `BaseModel`.

I added 2 new fields in the `BaseModel`. Given that all the models inherit from the `BaseModel`, they also got these 2 new fields, and now they are showing up in the admin pages. But I don't want these 2 fields to be displayed in the admin pages.

To exclude fields from the admin page, we normally use `excludes = [fields to be excluded]` in the admin class.

Is there a way to achieve this without touching all the admin classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [editable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#editable) field option.

> Field.editable
>
> If False, the field will not be displayed in the admin or any other ModelForm. They are also skipped during model validation. Default is True.

---

**The solution is to set `editable=False` for both these fields.**

Something like this:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    ...
    new_field_1 = models.IntegerField(    # Assumed that it is an integer field.
        editable=False,
        ...
    )
    new_field_2 = models.IntegerField(    # Assumed that it is an integer field.
        editable=False,
        ...
    )
```